# How to compare array of elements with the linq query result in c#

Tags: linq, lambda

How can i compare array of elements with the linq query. I will pass array of elements to the controller and i want to compare and display the records that only contains the passed elements.

I will pass an array of values like `["first","second","third"]` and i want to compare these records with the linq query and generate the result that contains these three records

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but you probably want something like this

```
String[] values = {"first", "second", "third"};

List<YourObject> query = 
    (from p in this.db.table 
    where values.Contains(p.values) select p).ToList();
```